# Can I play and fully enjoy Starcraft 2 using a Touchpad and not a Mouse?

Tags: starcraft-2

I would like to play with StarCraft 2 on my MacBook Pro but I often (bad habit) use my laptop sitting on the couch where Mouse is not an option.

Do you think I could be able to fully enjoy StarCraft just using the MBP touchpad?

Comment: No Nix Not a chance

Comment: Why isn't the mouse an option? My mouse works fine on the couch surface. It means the positioning of my hand is not optimal, but it should still be infinitely better than touchpad.

Comment: As an alternative, consider looking into one of those cool lap-desk dealies. They are super comfortable on a couch, and they give you an even surface for a mouse. You can even opt not to put it on your lap, and just keep it on the side for just the mousepad.

Comment: I also use my mouse on the couch with no problems

Comment: @Oak I usually stay lying down and not sit (as I said, bad habit :-) )

Comment: VTC: This question is *highly* subjective, and varies greatly based on the person. A believe that something like "How can you compensate for the lack of precision with a trackpad versus a mouse?" would be a good question, if you wished to ask it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since I'm playing a lot on my notebook I'm sometimes forced (by various circumstances) to play on the touchpad. While it is definitely possible and not as a pain as it might seem, it is a bit harder than using the mouse. I found out that with some practice I was able to play against Hard AI quite well (won most of the time) and even the campaign is playable (most missions on Medium though, many Hard achievements are **much** harder to get when using the touchpad).

The key to success is to use the keyboard as much as possible. Everything should be mapped to a  group - units, workers, production buildings. Use space to get to the action immediately when something happens. With some training, you should be ok. I wouldn't however attempt to play against people in 1v1 Quickmatch, especially if you are ranked gold or higher.

Comment: Most of this is still applicable even WITH a mouse. Keyboard = Fast(er), Mouse = Slow(er).

Comment: Against AI, always rush. Against AI APM etc. are not that big matters.

Comment: @VvxJason I find that's true with most computer actions.

Comment: Is there a way to scroll the map with two fingers the way all other windows on OSX work?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, it can be argued on, but I've yet to see someone playing on a touchpad with the same speed and accuracy he has on a mouse. And considering the fact that Starcraft II is not the most slug-paced game around, it'll probably leave you a bit frustrated.

You could try getting used to a trackball, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say no. You can play single player, but once you hit the ladder and multiplayer, the mouse control, speed and accuracy will greatly affect what you can do and how you can compete at certain levels.

Short answer: Your micro will be weak and your macro could technically take a hit as well.

Advantage: Playing with a touchpad could potentially help with your hotkeys and you will be in a good position when you do get a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I played it for a while using the Apple Magic Trackpad. It was playable, but I did find that i was at a disadvantage in fast paced games. Playing against the AI wasn't so bad though.

I think if Blizzard implemented some support for multi-touch gestures, it would make it much easier.

Comment: I suspect that no one is fast enough with gestures, reliably enough, for that to be true. Having said that, I'm very interested in gesture suggestions. (No, I don't work for Blizzard.)

Comment: I was thinking maybe something along the lines of a three finger drag movement for moving the map around, rather than trying to move the cursor to the edges of the screen, or using the keyboard or trying to click-drag on the minimap, or different combinations of swipes, 2, 3 or 4 finger to select different unit groups etc.

Answer (score 1):

While it might be enjoyable, I sometimes play without a mouse on my laptop to force myself to use the keyboard more. It's more of a practice exercise, as one of my weaknesses is macro-ing up my army while attacking. It's really ineffective to mouse back to your base to produce units and then back to the attack. Playing on the touchpad has made me a better keyboard user, which has improved my enjoyment when I actually do use a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Just switched to a mouse today, as I've been playing on a Macbook for the past couple of weeks. I'm brand new to StarCraft so I'd suck either way, but I do notice that because right clicking with the Macbook requires the command key, it's incredibly difficult to use hotkeys with the trackpad. I probably won't ever go back, my APM increased by 20 just because I was able to use the hotkeys more efficiently with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I have a mouse, a touchpad and a trackball, and I always use a combination of the trackball (if I need really accurate movement when microing something) and the touchpad (when I'm using the keyboard almost exclusively - when I'm macroing hard). I just find it easier to play with a trackball than a mouse generally, and using the touchpad allows me to comfortably use all of the hotkeys at once.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use an MBP without a mouse and I do just fine- but I haeve yet to attempt with one.  I don't feel frustrated with the trackpad speed or accuracy, but I would love some gesture controls.